# Elasticsearch set limit and offset using RestHighLevelClient

Tags: java, elasticsearch, limit, offset

I search in Elasticsearch using `MultiSearchRequest` by part of the field:

```
@Override
public Collection<Map<String, Object>> findContractsByIndexAndWord(String index, String type, String word) throws CommonUserException {
    MultiSearchRequest request = new MultiSearchRequest();
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, ID_FIELD, word));
    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, PROVIDER_ID_FIELD, word));

    MultiSearchResponse searchResponse;
    try (RestHighLevelClient client = getClient()) {
        searchResponse = client.multiSearch(request);
        return formContracts(searchResponse);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CommonUserException(ELASTIC_EXCEPTION, ELASTIC_EXCEPTION);
    }
}

private SearchRequest formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(String index, String type, String field, String word) {
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index);
    searchRequest.types(type);
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery(field, word));
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    return searchRequest;
}
private Collection<Map<String, Object>> formContracts(MultiSearchResponse response) {
    Collection<Map<String, Object>> contracts = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < response.getResponses().length; i++) {
        SearchHit[] hits = response.getResponses()[i].getResponse().getHits().getHits();
        for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
            if (!contracts.contains(hit.getSourceAsMap())) {
                contracts.add(hit.getSourceAsMap());
            }
        }
    }
    return contracts;
}
```

How can I add to this request limit and offset of the result?

Answer (score 4):

From the [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search.html#CO117-3) (last version)

> Here are a few examples of some common options:
>
> ```
> SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();  //1
> sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user", "kimchy"));   //2
> sourceBuilder.from(0);                                            //3
> sourceBuilder.size(5);                                            //4
> sourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));       //5
> ```
>
> 1. Create a SearchSourceBuilder with default options.
> 2. Set the query. Can be any type of QueryBuilder
> 3. Set the from option that determines the result index to start searching from. Defaults to 0.
> 4. Set the size option that determines the number of search hits to return. Defaults to 10.
> 5. Set an optional timeout that controls how long the search is allowed to take.

Size and From are what is usually known as offset/limit.

You may want to have a look at the scroll API if you use it intensively, as offset/limit based result traversal may be kind of slow under certain circumstances, and the scroll API is the way to avoid most of this (if you come from a SQL background as I guess from the limit/offset terminology, think of the Scroll API as the equivalent of keeping a SQL Cursor open to carry on from where you left off iterating).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I search by one field - it works correct, but if I want to search by multiple fields - result is, for example for size 5, not always a 5 documents, it may be more than 5, I think thats because I build SearchSourceBuilder for every entity's field.

Comment: I also think it's a different issue. You're building a MultiSearchRequest, so you have to think about what you are trying to achieve. What does it mean to set the size of a "subrequest", vs. setting the size of the SultiSearchRequest.